# Compiling libcurl for Android 64

Tags: android, openssl, libcurl

I'm trying to create a Android 64-bit libcurl static library with SSL support.

I first compile OpenSSL with the help of this script https://github.com/cocochpie/android-openssl/blob/master/build-all-arch.sh. I've modified it so that it only builds for Android 64-bit and I see the following output:

```
ANDROID_TOOLS = aarch64-linux-android-gcc aarch64-linux-android-gcc-ranlib aarch64-linux-android-ld
Error: ANDROID_SYSROOT is not valid. Please edit this script.
CHECK_CROSS_COMPILER =
arch = arm64
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: /opt/android/ndk-bundle
ANDROID_ARCH: arch-arm64
ANDROID_EABI: aarch64-linux-android-4.9
ANDROID_API: android-19
ANDROID_SYSROOT: /opt/android/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm64
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN: /opt/android/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin
FIPS_SIG: /openssl-1.1.0g/util/incore
CROSS_COMPILE:
ANDROID_DEV: /opt/android/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm64/usr
CROSS COMPILE ENV :
Can't open Makefile.org: No such file or directory.
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0g (0x1010007fL)
    no-afalgeng     [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_AFALGENG
    no-apps         [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_APPS
    no-asan         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_ASAN
    no-asm          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_ASM
    no-capieng      [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_CAPIENG
    no-comp         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_COMP (skip dir)
    no-crypto-mdebug [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG
    no-crypto-mdebug-backtrace [default]  OPENSSL_NO_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_BACKTRACE
    no-dynamic-engine [forced]
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128
    no-egd          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EGD
    no-engine       [option]   OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE (skip engines)
    no-fuzz-afl     [default]  OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_AFL
    no-fuzz-libfuzzer [default]  OPENSSL_NO_FUZZ_LIBFUZZER
    no-heartbeats   [default]  OPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS
    no-hw           [option]   OPENSSL_NO_HW
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-msan         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MSAN
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP
    no-shared       [option]
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE
    no-ssl3         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_SSL3
    no-ssl3-method  [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL3_METHOD
    no-stdio        [option]   OPENSSL_NO_STDIO
    no-tests        [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_TESTS
    no-threads      [option]
    no-ubsan        [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UBSAN
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS
    no-zlib         [option]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
Configuring for linux-generic64
CC            =arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
CFLAG         =-Wall -O3  -fPIC -mandroid -I/opt/android/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm64/usr/include -B/opt/android/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm64/usr//lib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall
SHARED_CFLAG  =-fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE
DEFINES       =DSO_DLFCN HAVE_DLFCN_H NDEBUG OPENSSL_NO_DYNAMIC_ENGINE OPENSSL_PIC B_ENDIAN SHARED_EXTENSION=.so OPENSSL_PIC DSO_DLFCN HAVE_DLFCN_H
LFLAG         =
PLIB_LFLAG    =
EX_LIBS       =-ldl
APPS_OBJ      =
CPUID_OBJ     =mem_clr.o
UPLINK_OBJ    =
BN_ASM        =bn_asm.o
EC_ASM        =
DES_ENC       =des_enc.o fcrypt_b.o
AES_ENC       =aes_core.o aes_cbc.o
BF_ENC        =bf_enc.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4_enc.o rc4_skey.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5_enc.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=
CMLL_ENC      =camellia.o cmll_misc.o cmll_cbc.o
MODES_OBJ     =
PADLOCK_OBJ   =
CHACHA_ENC    =chacha_enc.o
POLY1305_OBJ  =
BLAKE2_OBJ    =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =/usr/bin/perl
```

This step appears to complete successfully as the /openssl-1.1.0g directory ends up with a libssl.a and libcrypto.a as I would expect.

I then download curl and run the following configuration:

```
./configure \
       --host=$CHOST \
       --target=aarch64-linux-android \
       --with-ssl=/openssl-1.1.0g \
       --with-zlib \
       --enable-ftp \
       --enable-http \
       --enable-ipv6 \
       --enable-static \
       --disable-dict \
       --disable-file \
       --disable-gopher \
       --disable-imap \
       --disable-ldap \
       --disable-ldaps \
       --disable-manual \
       --disable-pop3 \
       --disable-proxy \
       --disable-rtsp \
       --disable-shared \
       --disable-smb \
       --disable-smtp \
       --disable-sspi \
       --disable-telnet \
       --disable-tftp \
       --without-gnutls \
       --without-libidn \
       --without-librtmp
```

The output of this command is:

```
curl version:     7.56.1
  Host setup:       aarch64-unknown-linux-android
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,mbedtls,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     enabled
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         POSIX threaded
  IPv6 support:     enabled
  Unix sockets support: enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn2,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  no      (--enable-manual)
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     no      (--enable-rtsp)
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        FTP HTTP
```

If I'm interpreting this correctly the libcurl config is not finding the SSL library and building without SSL support.

Is that correct? If so, I would guess that this would happen if a) it cannot find the required files or b) it does find the required files but they are compiled for a different architecture.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong here?

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested I looked through the config.log file. This part looks suspicious:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'conftest' '-v' '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=softfp' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mthumb' '-D' '__ANDROID_API__=19' '-Werror=implicit-function-declaration' '-O2' '-Wno-system-headers' '-v' '-mandroid' '-march=armv7-a' '-mfloat-abi=softfp' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mthumb' '-D' '__ANDROID_API__=19' '-D' 'ANDROID' '-I' '/openssl-1.1.0g/include' '-I' '/openssl-1.1.0g/include/openssl' '-L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/include' '-march=armv7-a' '-L/openssl-1.1.0g/lib' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/collect2 -plugin /opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccFgY2c5.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ldl -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --sysroot=/opt/android/toolchain-arm/sysroot --eh-frame-hdr -dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker -X -m armelf_linux_eabi -z noexecstack -z relro -z now -o conftest /opt/android/toolchain-arm/sysroot/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/include -L/openssl-1.1.0g/lib -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/armv7-a/thumb -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/armv7-a/thumb -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../lib/gcc -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib -L/opt/android/toolchain-arm/sysroot/usr/lib --fix-cortex-a8 /tmp/ccxx0SSC.o -lcrypto -lz -lgcc -lc -ldl -lgcc /opt/android/toolchain-arm/sysroot/usr/lib/crtend_android.o
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function close_console: error: undefined reference to 'stdin'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function close_console: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'signal'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function read_string_inner: error: undefined reference to 'tcsetattr'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'tcgetattr'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'stdin'
/openssl-1.1.0g/lib/libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o):ui_openssl.c:function open_console: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Always, ALWAYS, when configure fails to do what you want, you start out by reading `config.log` around the checks for the particular thing you want to investigate. Like the SSL library detection in this case....

Comment: I've posted an update with log information.

Comment: consider editing your question and add the relevant piece of the log there...

Comment: So what I'm thinking is that I'm building OpenSSL and Libcurl with either the incorrect versions of NDK and Android SDK or the incorrect combination of those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a fantastic script for building what I needed: https://github.com/leenjewel/openssl_for_ios_and_android.

The big take away for me here was that if you see 'SSL support: no' and you are expecting to see 'yes' then it's one of two things: 1) it cannot find the path to SSL or 2) the path might be there but the compiled SSL is for the wrong architecture.

As Daniel Stenberg mentioned config.log is your friend here.